# Show content based on page number

Tags: pagination, page-template

I have a post that I would like to split in to 5 pages and depending on which page the user is on the image at the top of the page needs to change.

So page 1 of the Post displays the image in custom field image_1, then page 2 displays the image in custom field 2 and so on...

I've set up my custom fields for the post but can't find reference to the function for detecting what page the user is on so I can add the function in to my template, what is the function I should be using?

Comment: can you share the codes where you have spilt the single post into five?

Comment: It's just using the standard <!--nextpage--> code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current post page can be detected using `get_query_var('page');`.

note that if you do not pass any page the page 1 is shown, but `get_query_var('page');` will be `0`;

So in your `function.php` you can add:

```
function get_page_image() {
  global $post;
  if ( ! is_object($post) || ! isset($post->ID) ) return;
  $page = get_query_var('page');
  if ( empty($page) ) $page = 1;
  $field = 'image_' . $page;
  return get_post_meta($post->ID, $field, true);
}
```